# Cannot read property 'get' of undefined Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am trying to inject the `HttpClient`  in my Configuration service like :

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';


export function config() {
   return new Configuration();
}


@Injectable()
export class Configuration {

    public static createConfiguration(): any {
        return config;
    };

    constructor(private http?: HttpClient) {
        debugger;
        if (environment.production) {            
            this.readConfigurations().subscribe(res => {
                console.log(res);
            })

        }
    }



    readConfigurations() {
        return this.http.get('../../assets/config/config.json')
            .map((res: any) => {
                res.json();
            }
            );
    }
}
```

So, you can see that I have injected the `HttpClient` in the constructor parameter.

In my app module, I have declared this Configuration under

Providers:

```
   { provide: Configuration, useFactory: Configuration.createConfiguration(), deps: [] },
```

But, when i am running my application i am getting :

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
>           at Configuration.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/config/configuration.service.ts.Configuration.readConfigurations
>   (configuration.service.ts:69)
>           at new Configuration (configuration.service.ts:59)
>           at config (configuration.service.ts:10)
>           at _callFactory (core.es5.js:9552)
>           at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.es5.js:9506)
>           at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9488)
>           at _createClass (core.es5.js:9533)
>           at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.es5.js:9503)
>           at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9488)

Please help me in what I am doing wrong.

Edit:

App Module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [HttpClientModule],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,

    ],
  providers: [
    Logger, LOG_LOGGER_PROVIDERS,
    { provide: Configuration, useFactory: Configuration.createConfiguration(), deps: [] },
   ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Are you in production? If yes you call the readConfigurations() method that needs an instance of Http to work

Comment: You could be missing the HttpClientModule but the error it generates is usually obvious in the console.

Comment: @John its imported in app module

Comment: @MicheleDaRin can you please help me because i am not getting instance of http there

Comment: ah, ok. Also, it's considered extremely bad practice to make a network call in a constructor. You should not do that, and I suspect it's one of your problems here. Create another method readConfig() on your configuration object so Angular can initialize your object without hitting the network.

Comment: Actually reading your error messages, that's looks be exactly the problem.

Comment: @John but i need instance of http where i make a network call from constructor or from another method. But, the point is i am not getting instance itself

Comment: @Rohitesh it's because it may not have been created yet. Can you post your entire AppModule configuration?  I'd like to see your (at)NgModule

Comment: @John please find in edit

Comment: Your stack-trace shows that this error is occurring when you call your exported `config` function. ("at config (configuration.service.ts:10)"), so of course `http` is going to be null as you don't pass it in to the constructor.

Comment: @Rohitesh I got it to work in my current angular 6 project (lucky you). See my answer, it's a bit tricky.

Comment: I wonder what are you even trying to archive here. If you define the dependency as *optional* with `?` (notice that you should use the `@Optional` decorator for this purpose), then **why** do you directly invoke an instance method in the dependency without null-checking first?

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work:

In your `@NgModule` you need to provide the dependency of `HttpClient` for the `deps` section.

Change:

```
{ provide: Configuration, useFactory: Configuration.createConfiguration(), deps: [] },
```

to:

```
{ provide: Configuration, useFactory: Configuration.createConfiguration(), deps: [HttpClient] },
```

and in your `Configuration` object, you need to add the `HttpClient` as a dependency injection to the exported `config` function up top and pass it to the constructor:

Change:

```
export function config() {
  return new Configuration();
}
```

to:

```
export function config(http: HttpClient) {
   return new Configuration(http);
}
```

Otherwise, the angular framework factory mechanism does not know it needs to pass an HttpClient to your object. This should work (it does for me)

That being said, accessing the network from a constructor remains a **very bad** practice.

Comment: Hello john this approach helped me and i am able to get the instance of http but when i am doing http cal to load the json i am getting this error                                                                                         
                                   
  ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at ScalarObservable.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:177)

Comment: I am making http call like                      http.get('./../../assets/config/config.json')
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log('Data Loaded ' + data);
        });

Comment: Not sure, that looks like a json error and it seems unrelated to the prior problem. what does your json look like? can you update your question with the data inside your config.json?